# Spending loads of time in already optimized class -> Anything wrong?

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap

I have a simple 2D Point class that I wrote myself. My Points are immutable and I need to create loads of them, for memory efficiency I created a cache to fetch those that are already there.

Total unique points I use during the process around 100_000. I need to fetch loads of them multiple times.

While profiling my app I noticed that most of the time is spent in this class.

I wonder if I did anything tremendously stupid or the time spent really is because I need to create so many points. Can I optimize this class any further? (And yes - I need the concurrent access)

This is the code:

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
private static final Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Point>> POINT_CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private static final boolean USE_CACHE = true;

public final int row;
public final int column;


private int hashCache = -1;


public static Point newPoint(int row, int column){
    if(!USE_CACHE) return new Point(row,column);
    return POINT_CACHE.computeIfAbsent(row, k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>()).computeIfAbsent(column, v -> new Point(row , column));
}

public static Point newPoint(Point point){
    return newPoint(point.row,point.column);
}

protected Point(int row, int column) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Point point = (Point) o;
    return row == point.row && column == point.column;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    //Assuming the matrix is less than 65k x 65k, this will return unique hashes
    if (hashCache == -1) hashCache = (row << 16) | column;
    return hashCache;

    //return Objects.hash(row, column);

}

//Getter
}
```

[Profiler Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ry1S.png)

Comment: Not what you asked for, but I don't understand the point of the `Point newPoint(Point point)` method - if `Point`s are immutable, you could shorten it to `Point newPoint(Point point) { return point; }`

Comment: True, never noticed. But the constructor is almost never used

Comment: The (nested, no less) `ConcurrentHashMap` certainly introduces a lot of overhead. I don't know exactly, but it's well possible the caching is actually counterproductive this way. But if you're using a profiler, can't you see exactly where the time is wasted?

Comment: I introduced the cache as my heap space were running low due to the amount of created points. But also was thinking if this is really helpful. Profiling result is attached

Comment: Couldn't you use row + column (perhaps a `Pair`) as map key? That way you wouldn't need nested maps

Comment: Actually, Yah...maybe? I think I could just use the method that I already use within the hashCode as key. This should be unique in my use case and therefore maybe optimal. I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `ConcurrentHashMap` operations are expensive.

They also use a lot of memory.  Even more memory than a regular `HashMap`.

So unless you get an average cache hit rate over 90%, you are probably going to use more memory in the `ConcurrentHashMap` objects than you are saving in not creating duplicate `Point` objects.

The other thing to observe is since your `Point` objects have `int` values as their `row` and `column` attributes, you *could* simply encode each distinct point as a `long` ... and entirely remove the need for the `Point` objects and the cache.

Comment: This is probably the best answer as it clearly removes the whole class from existence. We decided not to do this and just remove the overhead of nested hashmaps. Doing this we realized that our hash function is not working as we can have negativ rows and columns and therefore two's complent interferes. Any good UNIQUE hash function that we can use as a key? Has to support negative row/columns but not more than at most 5000. Integer should have enough unique space though